# About topology in $R^n$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, matrices, analysis

Suppose $F_1,F_2$ is closed in $R^n$,and $F_1\cap F_2=\emptyset$,proof there exist$G_1,G_2 $are open set,such that $G_1\cap G_2=\emptyset$,and $F_1\subset G_1,F_2\subset G_2$

Attempt

Suppose $a_n=\frac{1}{n}$
And $F_i\subset \cup _{x\in F_i}B_{a_n}(x)=G_i,i=1,2$

Then I want to use Contradiction,I can get $x_n\in G_1,y_n\in G_2,and z_n\in G_1\cap G_2$,satisfy $|z_n-x_n|<\frac{1}{n},|z_n-y_n|<\frac{1}{n}$

I don’t know what should I do next

Comment: Why don't you just take $G_1=F_1$ and $G_2=F_2$?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos sorry I have adjusted it

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos the question had a modification